# Eighth +quarter notes

Tags: theory, practice, learning

Am I right counting it this way or not?
May someone help me? 
Thanks 
[image: beats in a bar]

Comment: Is your bottom sheet supposed to be in alignment with your top? If so, you're not right counting this way.

Comment: I explained in a previous answer how to count each beat in two. So since this is in 4/4, count 8, and each quaver will be one count, each crotchet will be a count of two. Please try to use the information in answers to help you *understand* rather tha merely asking each time you feel you have a problem. -1.

Answer (score 2):

Almost; the '2' and '4' don't have a corresponding note but are the second half of the quarter notes. The arrows below indicate how the rhythm is to be counted:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The note flags have meaning, so your quarter notes need to be on 1+ and 3+ while your sketch places them on 2 and 4.  Basically, the quarter notes are "early eighths", stealing time from the could-have-been-quarter notes before them.